# I need a multiselect drop down without pressing control key?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am new to flex and I am creating a combo box with itemrenderers containing check boxes, I want multiple checkboxes to be selected without the ctrl key, I searched many links but all of them gives me the ctrl option only I am looking to create it without pressing ctrl key?

the code for my combobox is

```
<mx:ComboBox id="cbx" width="200" x="819.2" y="1.5" prompt="--Select Flow--" click="ComboSelection(event)" >
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                  <mx:Component>
                      <mx:CheckBox label="{data.label}" selected="{data.selected}" click="outerDocument.LoadOrderCh(event)" />
                  </mx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
              </mx:ComboBox>
```

I tried with the click event in the check and stop propagating but it works only for the selected index, for others the dropdown closed immediately

```
public function LoadOrderCh(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        evt.stopPropagation();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had task with creating multi chooser dropDown.
I created SkinnableComponent and it's skin is

```
<fx:Metadata>
<![CDATA[
    [HostComponent("ru.vemtek.dynamics.filters.MultipleDropDownList")]
    ]]>
</fx:Metadata>

<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal"/>
    <s:State name="open"/>
    <s:State name="disabled"/>
</s:states>

<s:PopUpAnchor id="popUp"  displayPopUp.normal="false" displayPopUp.open="true" includeIn="open"
               left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" itemDestructionPolicy="auto"
               popUpPosition="below" popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth="true">
    <s:List id="dropDownList"
            allowMultipleSelection="true"
            left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"/>
</s:PopUpAnchor>

<s:Button id="openButton" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" focusEnabled="false" tabEnabled="false"
          skinClass="ru.vemtek.skins.MultipleDropDownListButtonSkin"/>
```

```
public class MultipleDropDownList extends SkinnableComponent {
    [SkinPart(required="true")]
    public var openButton:Button;

    [SkinPart(required="true")]
    public var dropDownList:List;

    private var _dropDownController:DropDownController;
```

`...`

```
dropDownList.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onDropDownListClick);
...
private function onDropDownListClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
        if (!event.ctrlKey && !event.shiftKey) {
            dropDownController.closeDropDown(false);
            invalidateSkinState();
        }
    }
```

In function DropDownListClick I can customize a behavior of closing on non-closing list.

Maybe this idea will be helpful for you.